# Dplyr Tidyyeval for built variable names

Tags: r, dplyr, lazy-evaluation, rlang

I am trying to build a function that will allow me to perform functions on columns that start with a specific prefix. I am struggling to figure out how to get the names to evaluate to the correct thing.

I've looked at the `dplyr` website where it talks about [programming](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) but couldn't quite figure out how to make it evaluate properly.

I am making use of the most current version of `dplyr` on CRAN (v0.70) where @hadley has introduced `tidyeval`

Reprex

```
library(tidyverse)

tbl1 <- tibble(
  urn = c(1 ,2 ,3 ),
  a_width = c(10,20,30),
  a_height = c(12,13,14),
  b_width = c(25,50,75),
  b_height = c(25,50,75)
)

my_mean <- function(x, group) {
  width <- paste0(quo_name(group), "_width")
  height <- paste0(quo_name(group), "_height")

  summarise(x, 
  !!paste0(group, "_mean_width") := mean(!!width),          
  !!paste0(group, "_mean_height") := mean(!!height)          
  )  
}

my_mean(tbl1, "a")

# # A tibble: 1 x 2
# a_mean_width a_mean_height
# <dbl>         <dbl>
#   1           NA            NA
# Warning messages:
#   1: In mean.default("a_width") :
#   argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
# 2: In mean.default("a_height") :
#   argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Comment: I think you missed a comma in the `summarise` command.

Comment: You are correct, the comma was missed however that is more a case of my poor typing, rather than the cause of the issue.

Comment: Sure, I was just trying to reproduce your error and the missed comma made this impossible :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!!width` returns the *string* `"a_width"`. You have to do `!!sym(width)` to turn it into a *name*. Similarly for `!!height`.

Comment: I think you need `!!sym(width)` not `sym(!!width)`

Comment: I get an error saying 'could not find function sym'

Comment: `sym` is a function from the rlang package which is what dplyr uses for this stuff

Comment: `!!sym(width)` is the one. Feel free to edit the answer and I'll confirm it.

Comment: Edited, not at my computer at the moment